# How can a transaction be out of gas but still complete?

Tags: gas, out-of-gas

This one has me scratching my head:
This transaction (which sent in a value of 0.01 ETH) executed correctly according to etherscan:

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x31180d097b7baf3e9804334d24bb2c142dd8a58486bcb487bbb567bac9d3ba63

However:

1- I got an error in the callback that said:

> "Error: The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount."

..and the Total Gas Used looks to be higher than the max gas allowed.

2- Although the Tx says that 0.005 ETH was transferred to two wallets, neither of them actually show that transfer having happened:
https://etherscan.io/address/0xc122ca236edf7b33fb73fbb459a08f7935e6c96b
https://etherscan.io/address/0x39267ec3f4e1610cd871d3545e01918f1dba7b84

So I am totally puzzled. If there was not enough gas, I would expect the TX to fail and to lose the gas, **but not** the 0.01 ETH in value.
If it did not fail, why did I get the error in the callback and no transfer of value to the wallets?

At the moment it looks to me like 0.01 ETH just disappeared - it left the paying wallet, but did not arrive in the receiving wallets.

Can anyone explain?

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you provide information on how this transaction was created ? Just a raw transaction with some data or using web3 / truffle ?

Comment: From etherscan and etherchain it seem that it has executed correctly, in both accounts if you look in the internal transaction tab in etherscan you can see there is a transaction for block 3931947, tx 0x31180d09...

Comment: Hi Nikita, the tx was created using web3.

Comment: Hi Ismael, I agree with you but then where did the ETH go? It does not appear in the receiving wallets.

Comment: It has happened again with this transaction https://etherscan.io/tx/0x7950786cac6c55b37ae0386dc567c352017054dc2c537acf87ff976932d9f62d    This time it does not appear to have run out of gas, but I got the same error in the callback and the payment has not gone to the receiving wallets... totally stumped!

Comment: In fact, I have realised that the payments are being made: they appear under "internal transactions".... BUT then why am I getting a failure callback for a successful tx? And this does not happen on Ropsten. The same contract executes flawlessly. Would really appreciate any insight!

Answer (score 1):

I have checked the transactions you provided in etherscan.

To see the questioned transfers in target accounts, go to the target account and click on "Internal transactions" tab. The inbound transfers are visible there.

Comment: yes! I just saw that! That was my bad! But what about the error message? Why am I getting an error callback for a thing that succeeded?

Comment: Hard to tell just looking at the transactions - they all seem to have been executed just fine. Error messages might be somewhat misleading since all throws in Ethereum are equal.

Comment: you mean the throw is for something else entirely? How the hell does one debug that then? :-(

Comment: What client are you using?

Comment: to submit? web3 via  Metamask.. that what you mean?

Comment: It might be related to https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-plugin/issues/1361

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the sender spent all the gas therefore the balance has been updated by the spent_gas*gas_price amount, i.e. the Ethereum state is changed and it should be "engraved" in the blockchain.